# Is there a way to display a PDF in an asp.net webpage without frames?

Tags: pdf

I have a PDF document that needs to be pulled up in the browser, edited, and saved.  I can save via the embedded adobe toolbar, along with all the other acrobat functions.  But, what I am trying to see is if there is a way to display the PDF in a webpage alongside web controls.

For example, in the top part of the webpage I have a dropdownlist.  It has a list of PDFs.  I select one and the bottom part of the webpage opens up with the PDF.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is typically done with an [iframe](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_iframe.asp).

Comment: Did this work for you? I haven't been able to get a pdf to render in the iframe. It always pops up in a separate browser window.

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for something like [Scribd's iPaper viewer](http://www.scribd.com/tools/ipaper)?

You can embed it on your site or host with them.

Comment: Michael - I replied below with a different idea but thank you for the reference to iPaper.  That is a very cool technology!

Comment: Doesn't Scribd use FlashPaper?

Comment: I'm not sure this will work because it says it converts things to iPaper.  I have to have the normal Acrobat functionality for editing, signing, etc.  Thank you for your link.

Comment: Ah, I see. I thought you could still download the doc in its original format, though (pdf). That may not work I guess if you need the actual acrobat experience inline. In that case, I think the iFrame is probably best.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, you'll have to use either Frames, or iFrames. Perhaps you can also get it via an `<object>` tag, but that might get browser-specific.

Answer (score 0):

I would contact the people at ceTe (makers of DynamicPDF).  Their product permits you to dynamically replace your page output with a PDF file but this involves changing the entire page (the mime-type will be pdf).  Is it possible to output the page to a panel instead?  I don't think so, but they would be the people I would turn to.